# Check file modify date with batch

Tags: windows-server-2003-r2

I am trying to use batch to check if file was modified today.

Can you please help me with your suggestions? Below is the code with which I am facing some issue.

```
SET filename="D:\empty\xyz.txt"
forfiles /m %filename% /d 0 && (
    echo The file was modified today
) || (
    echo The file has not been modified today
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a path within the `/M` search mask.  You need to use the `/P` path argument.

```
C:\> REM This does not work
C:\> SET FILENAME=D:\empty\xyz.txt
C:\> FORFILES /M %FILENAME%
ERROR: Files of type "D:\empty\xyz.txt" not found.

C:\> REM This does work
C:\> SET FILENAME=xyz.txt
C:\> FORFILES /P "D:\empty" /M %FILENAME%
"xyz.txt"
```

Please see the [Forfiles documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) for more details.